# jodatime -> parse error utc datetime string

Tags: java, jodatime

Currently, I'm trying to parse a DateTime using jodatime library.

```
String stringLiteral = "09/05/2016 12:25:39"
try {
  DateTime utcDateTime = new DateTime(stringLiteral, DateTimeZone.UTC);
  this.expressionType = ExpressionEnumType.date;
  this.expressions.add(ConstantImpl.create(utcDateTime.toDate()));
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e)
{
  this.expressionType = ExpressionEnumType.string;
  this.expressions.add(ConstantImpl.create(stringLiteral));
}
```

However, jodatime tells me:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "09/05/2016 12:25:39" is malformed at "/05/2016 12:25:39"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor of `DateTime` cannot parse a string in any arbitrary format into a `DateTime` object. If you want to use the constructor in this way, the string must be in one of the ISO 8601 formats, and your string `"09/05/2016 12:25:39"` is not.

Use another method to parse the date, where you can specify the format yourself. For example:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
                                            .withZoneUTC();

DateTime utcDateTime = DateTime.parse(stringLiteral, formatter);
```

Comment: @Jordi The [API docs](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#DateTime-java.lang.Object-org.joda.time.DateTimeZone-) say: look at [`ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeParser()`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/ISODateTimeFormat.html#dateTimeParser--). It should be a string in [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. For example: `2016-05-09T12:25:39`